# How can I block off my stairs while I repair the walls?

Tags: drywall, child-safety

I have an epileptic son that I have to keep off of our stairs.  We have some great childproof stair gates installed currently.  I have redone all of the drywall in the house except the stairwell because I cannot think of a way to keep him off of the stairs for a few days while I mud, sand, mud, sand, texture, and paint the stairwell.  I don't mind reinstalling the gates after that.

As you can see, I cant even screw a piece of plywood over the whole thing because I need to do the drywall all the way around the corner.  I am using a hopper so doing it in two stages will not blend well.

[image]

Comment: Since it's only for a couple of days, would it work to just block off all the surrounding rooms rather than the staircase itself?

Comment: If I have to, but he is special needs in a lot of ways, and if we start messing with his routine too badly it becomes a nightmare.

Comment: Can you attach something to the outside corner (across the opening, instead of inside the opening)?

Comment: Maybe.  Although, I am going to be spraying texture all the way around that corner.  So, I would rather not put holes anywhere on those walls.  Is there a way to screw or nail into that trim that I could fill back in?  Actually, I think I just figured it out.  I will screw into the trim and then replace it after everything.  Thank you for getting me thinking in the right direction.  Put that as an answer and I will give it to you.

Comment: Put a piano at the top of the stairs.  It should be heavy enough that he can't shift it.  And you can lock him in.  You'll have you climb over it yourself but that shouldn't be a problem ;)